# Symfony deleteaction multi table delete

Tags: symfony

Hi I want to delete the product in the other table when I delete a product. And I want to do this on the controller.

```
$deleteQuery = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->delete('TechnoSiteBundle:Sepet', 's')
        ->where('s.id = ' . $request->get('id'))->getQuery();
    $deleted = $deleteQuery->getResult();
```

OR

```
$deleteQuery = $em->getRepository('TechnoSiteBundle:Ebatlar')->createQueryBuilder('table1')
        ->where('table1.id')
        ->leftJoin('table1.sepet', 'table2')
        ->andWhere('table2.ebat1')
        ->delete('table1.id = table2.productid')
        ->getQuery();
    $deleted = $deleteQuery->getResult();
```

I want to delete two related products. I get this error when I use Cascade;

```
2/2DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM ebatlar WHERE id = ?' with params [30]:
```

Comment: You will need to provide more details. Can you edit your question and add the code of your related entities (don't need getters and setters)?

Comment: You made an edit, but doesn't seems to have done what was asked of you. No-one will be able to help you at this rate. When we ask something, there is a reason behind it. Once again, add your two entities to your question (without the getters and setters)

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you should do with so little information about your entities.

Some things to explore:

- If your two `product` rows are related, you might want to look into using a [cascade={"remove"}](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) annotation somewhere.
- Nothing prevents you from running two queries if you want to manually delete two entities.
- Some notes about best practice with Doctrine, Symfony and MVC in general (not directly related to your question, and you don't *have* to follow these guidelines, but it's things you definitely *should* follow as that will make your life much easier in the long run):

  - You're not supposed to put too much logic in controllers. In Symfony, you want your controllers to be almost empty. You create a service with the logic in it, and call it from your controller in the appropriate action. This has many advantages that you'll notice as your project grows: less code duplication, the freedom to change your model without changing your controllers, etc.
  - It's better to [bind parameters](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query) than to use concatenation like `->where('s.id = ' . $request->get('id'))`. This `$request->get('id')` is something the user can forge to insert basically anything he wants in your `where` clause.

Comment: I want to do this from the controller. Because I used the cascade relationship with another table.